# How to solve the overlap between a rectangle and a circle that collide

Tags: collision-detection

I have two figures - a circle and a rectangle and i have a method that checks whether the two figures collide. How to prevent them  from overlapping during collision?

Comment: Check whether they are _going_ to collide instead of if they _are_ colliding maybe.

Comment: If you are able to check if they are colliding/overlapping, you should be able to calculate by how much. If you are doing a reactive collision, then you should shift either the circle or the rectangle away by that calculated amount.

Comment: Very important: is this physically accurate motion, or is it kinematic motion (i.e. controlled purely by player input, without momentum etc.)? -- This impacts on the answer in several ways.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use [raycasting collision](http://www.leadwerks.com/files/Tutorials/CPP/Collision_And_Raycasting.pdf) for the circles, and traditional box-collisions for rect-rect collisions.

Answer (score 1):

if the speed of the objects is constant (or you can predict it accurately) you can check if they are going to collide, if yes don't move object (or move them so they touch side to side)

one other thing you can do is save previous location, calculate object's new location, if objects collide, move to previous location